# In Hibernate, why does OneToOne need to be declared in both classes?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public class User {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Status status;
    // ...
}

public class Status {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "frn_user_id")
    private User user;
    // ...
}
```

It seems redundant. Why can't there just be one declaration above User's Status that says each User has one Status and says which column it's joined on?

Comment: You can, but if you only define one end of it, you can't go the other way.  The annotation in `User` tells how to get from `User` to `Status`.  The annotation in `Status` tells how to get from `Status` to `User`.

Comment: in unidirectional you define on one and in bidirectional you define on both entities.Example of unidirectional mapping: http://fruzenshtein.com/one-to-one-unidirectional-primary-key/